# Looking for options for a cross platform mobile app to communicate with a micro-controller

Tags: java, android, ios, mobile

I have written a Java SE desktop application that communicates with a micro-controller. It displays data received from it and send updates to it, communicating constantly. It uses some third party libraries and the javax.comm library to communicate over serial. We are currently investigating our options for developing a cross platform mobile app that has the same functionality. Ultimately, this new application would be able to be compiled and run from the desktop, a mobile phone and a tablet. I have researched a few options (Oracle's new ADF mobile, phoneGap, Java ME, etc.) but am wondering if anyone has any suggestions of what would be best. Feel free to ask any follow up questions. Thanks in advance.

Ray

Comment: I've worked with the Android accessory toolkit which is compatible with Arduino. I don't think iOS is designed with any kind of interoperable accessory kit in mind. Think about commonality of interface first, what the Android devices all have is that micro USB port (which is a client/host combination), Desktops have USB hosts, iPhones have the iPhone accessory connector which isn't meant to act as a regular USB port. Your device will probably need to have two ports to do that and code that isn't shared on the device side, as well as a driver on the controller side.

Comment: First of all, thank you for the replies. They are all appreciated. It appears that my initial post lacked significantly in details. We do not exclusively communicate over Serial (also usb to serial adapter). We are also able to communicate via ethernet ( locally and remotely). We build the micro controller and are considering adding a Wi-Fi module to facilitate easier communication with the new application. That said, any recommendations as far as a development language?

Answer (score 2):

You are going to run into a couple challenges in doing this.  First of all, any cross-platform framework is almost immediately out.  Because of the significant differences outlined below, no framework I'm aware of has support for hardware connectivity.

**Hardware**

Your embedded device is currently communicating with a PC using RS-232 (UART).  This is a hardware interface that is not present on any consumer mobile devices (except the iPhone, but we'll get there).  The only common interfaces between all the major devices platforms (iOS, Android, Windows Phone) that support a **point to point connection** from a hardware perspective are USB and Bluetooth.

Of the two, Bluetooth is the simpler one to adapt onto your embedded device because there are numerous Bluetooth modems on the market that simply attach to a UART and relay data over the link as a wire replacement using the RFCOMM protocol.

**SDK Support (i.e. how can an APP talk to this hardware?)**

- The Android SDK supports communication between an application and both interfaces.  Bluetooth came about in Android 2.0, and USB in Android 3.1.
- The iOS SDK supports communication with both since iOS 3.0.  It also supports Bluetooth LE as of iOS 5.
- The Windows Phone 8 SDK claims it will support Bluetooth connections, no word that I know of on USB support.

**Licensing**

This one really only applies to iOS, but it applies to **both** Bluetooth and USB/Serial.  In order to develop the **hardware** side of the iOS connection, you must be a member of their Made For iPod program.  Membership is free, but requires a significant amount of paperwork, and this really only gets you access to the documentation required to implement the protocols required by their proprietary connector.  Obtaining the connectors and other components required to make actual connection require further approvals that are not easy to obtain.

Bluetooth LE is the only connectivity standard on iOS that does not require membership in MFi to implement on both the hardware and software sides.  However, to date no other major mobile SDK supports this interface directly (Android is getting there).

Overall, my recommendation would be to lean towards adding Bluetooth and keep a close eye on the Bluetooth LE space.  If you can find an embedded module that runs dual mode, you can run LE to iOS devices and standard Bluetooth to other platforms.  This is the only license-free path I can think of, and as Bluetooth LE SDK support improves, the other devices can take advantage of that as well.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your tags, I presume "cross-platform" really just means android & iOS? That said, the question which cross-platform tool to chose has been answered quite a few times here, and doesn't really bear repeating. My recommendation is to go native, unless you really don't care about performance and optimal solutions.

That said, the interface to the hardware should be interesting. Android has the [Open Accessory Protocol](http://source.android.com/tech/accessories/aoap/aoa2.html) which is compatible with more recent versions of Android. This is for connections over USB. Apple is considerably more closed and requires licensing fees for the protocol, the connectors, etc. Your best bet would be to go with bluetooth or even wifi to interface your hardware to the mobile device. This would require only a single hardware design for both devices and would be somewhat future-proof as well.

Comment: Yes. Those two platforms in particular are our focus. Thanks for the information.